# How to clear NHibernate second level cache

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using HashtableCacheProvider as NHibernate second level cache provider for my web application. The problem is that it seems that NHibernate keeps cached data even if I restart my IIS. I thought that cached data will disappear when in that case. Can someone explain how does this thing work, and how can I clear the second level cache while using HashtableCacheProvider? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK HashtableCacheProvider runs in-proc so it dies with the process.  Are you sure you killed the worker process (aspnet_wp / w3wp)?

Comment: You were right. I thought that restarting IIS will kill those processes and start them again...strange...

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using HashtableCacheProvider in production.

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#cacheproviders